# Count Unique child records

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, lookup, roll-up-summary

I have 2 custom objects sharing a master detail realtionship. Object A is the parent, Object B is the child. Object B has a lookup field to contact. I want to create a filed on object A that will count the number of unique Object B records based on the contact look up field on object A e.g. If the following are object B records:

1. Peter Griffin, 10
2. Stuey Griffin, 20
3. Peter Griffin, 20
4. Brian Griffin, 5

The total number of records should be 3 considering Peter Griffin has been repeated. Any ideas?

Comment: don't think you can do with standard rollup summary field. you have to use triggers / batch jobs to get this.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is quite simple using the [`Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries`](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) tool. It's free and rigorously tested, and will not require you to write a single line of code. You can also backfill the data for free once you've configured your `Lookup Rollup Summary` using the provided <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button on the record detail. Simply create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` using the following data:

- Parent Object - `Object_A__c`
- Relationship Field - `Lookup_To_A__c`
- Child Object - `Object_B__c`
- Field to Aggregate - `Name`
- Aggregate Operation - **`Count Distinct`**
- Aggregate Result Field - `Child_Count_Field__c`